# anonymous function variable scope [js, ajax]

Tags: javascript, ajax, scope, anonymous-methods

```
$(".delete").click(
    function()  {
        var thesender = this;
        $(thesender).text("Del...");
        $.getJSON("ajax.php", {},
            function(data) {
                if (data["result"])
                    $(thesender).remove(); // variable defined outside
                else
                    alert('Error!');
            }
        );

        return false;
    }
);
```

This can cause problems if user clicks on another ".delete" before the ajax callback is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will fire another ajax request at the same time doing the same thing.  Whether that causes problems or not depends on the server side of things.

Typically you're deleting an id or key of some sort...I assume later in this code you will be, but for now it just issues another delete and call to `ajax.php`...what the result of this is entirely depends on that PHP page.

The callback happens for **that** ajax request when **that** ajax request finishes, each request in independent in this respect, so each callback is individually handled.  `thesender` is inside your current closure, so it's unique as well for each request and it's respective callback.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the `click` handler is called, a separate closure will be created, so each the AJAX callback will have a reference to the correct variable.

Therefore, you don't need to worry about it.  (Assuming that the server can handle the requests)

Answer (score 1):

It will fire another event. You could use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one) rather than click if you want the event to only fire once. Alternately, you can keep track as to whether an AJAX request is in progress; e.g by using [data](http://api.jquery.com/data) as follows:

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
  if ($(this).data('inProgress')) {
    // Request in progress; cancel?
    return;
  } else {
    $(this).data('inProgress', true);
  };
});
```

You could also achieve the same thing by using a global variable, adding classes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the one function tip  ^^